# How to turn on Local Changes - Default Changelist for Git in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, settings

I have two Windows 10 machines that have the exact same version of `IntelliJ Ultimate`. One of them has a `Local Changes` sub-tab in the Git tab, while the other does not. How do I turn this on/off so I can view changes? I would prefer this to be on rather than off. I have disables all non bundled plugins, but I am still seeing the same view in both. I have searched far and wide, and for whatever reason this setting has eluded me.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.7319.50, built on September 14, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
```

With Local Changes - Default Changelist
[image]

Without Local Changes - Default Changelist
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version Control window has been redesigned, you can find "Local Changes" under "Commit" tab on the left side of the window next to the  Project tab .

You can see what's new here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control

If you want to restore old view then you need to disable "use non-modal commit interface" under Preferences | Version Control | Commit

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

there is a easy ways to see local changes in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 just do as shows in screenshot.
[image]

and for Intellij just do global search for local changes and its shows git local changes.